# Try Catch/Exception for ManagementObjectNotFoundException and ActiveDirectory/Outlook

Tags: powershell

This might be a pretty basic question, but i haven't seen it on the forms. Bear with me i'm new to powershell

I'm trying to catch this exception(ManagementObjectNotFoundException) when a username is not found in our Active Directory Database.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
$user2 = Read-Host 'Enter account name of the user who is being added'
try {
$user = Read-Host 'Enter account name of the users email you wish to have access to'
Add-MailboxPermission –Identity $user -User $user2 -AccessRights FullAccess –InheritanceType All –Automapping $false
}
catch [ManagementObjectNotFoundException] {
    "User not found, try again"
     $user = Read-Host 'Enter account name of the users email you wish to have access to - Test'
}
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

I've also tried this option:

```
catch {
  Write-Host "An error occurred:"
  Write-Host $_
}
```

and I still receive this error:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'test1' couldn't be found on 'BN4PR12A003DC03.NAMPR12A003.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-MailboxPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BYAPR12MB2885,RequestId=25cd1eb7-055e-4250-bd43-6d2f5d528f12,TimeStamp=11/12/2019 9:38:16 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] C5EDB577,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddMailboxP 
   ermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: Are you getting the error being printed twice here? Or are you confused as to why you see the error when you called `Write-Host $_`?

Comment: I'm trying to catch the error and have the user type a valid username

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to throw what's called a **terminating error** in order to catch exceptions. You can set the error [action preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6) at your script level:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

or add `-ErrorAction Stop` to any cmdlets you want to catch errors from. Errors can't be caught if the exception is non-terminating. By default, errors are set to `Continue` but can be changed in one of the ways below:

## Error Action Preferences

- **Continue**: Displays the error but continues with execution. This is the default.
- **SilentlyContinue**: Hides the error and continues with execution.

  - Error is suppressed but is still added to the `$Error` collection.
- **Stop**: Throws a terminating error. The error action must be set to `Stop` to catch exceptions.
- **Inquire**: Asks the user what to do.
- **Suspend**: Used with Powershell Workflows. Suspends a Workflow job so it can be resumed later.
- **Ignore**: Similar to `SilentlyContinue`, it suppresses the error and continues executing. Can only be set with the `-ErrorAction` parameter, `Ignore` cannot be set to `$ErrorActionPreference`.

  - Unlike `SilentlyContinue`, `Ignore` will omit adding the error to the `$Error` collection.

---

#### A Note About Terminating errors

Note that terminating errors **cannot be converted to non-terminating** in the same way we can treat non-terminating errors as terminating. In other words, most exceptions originating from the framework or exceptions thrown from PowerShell with the `throw` statement must be handled via `try`/`catch`/`finally` blocks. Neither `$ErrorActionPreference` or `-ErrorAction` has any bearing on how the exception is handled.

As this restriction includes `Ignore` and `SilentlyContinue`, **you cannot suppress or ignore terminating errors with these preference values**. You ***must*** handle them to prevent script termination.