# Catching errors in powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, error-handling, workflow

I'm relatively new to powershell scripting so I have been coding based on multiple examples that I have seen online.

I have a script that executes multiple batch files in parallel and each batch file contains a bcp command to execute.  I'm trying to catch any errors that may occur running the batch file but it's not working as expected.  I specifically forced an error on product.bat by having an invalid select syntax.

```
workflow Test-Workflow 
{
    Param ([string[]] $file_names)
    $file_names = Get-Content "D:/EDW/data/informatica/ming/Powersh/bcplist.lst"
    foreach -parallel ($line in $file_names) 
    {
       try
       {
          Write-Output ("processing... " + $line + ".bat")
          start-process D:/EDW/data/informatica/ming/Powersh/$line.bat -ErrorAction Stop -wait
       }
       catch
       {
          $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
          $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
          Write-Output $line : $ErrorMessage  $FailedItem
       }
   }
}
```

```
bcplist.lst:
        ing_channel
        ing_product
```

```
ing_channel:
        bcp "SELECT  * FROM CHANNEL" queryout ing_channel.txt -T -S99.999.999.9,99999 -t"\t" -c -q
```

```
ing_product:
        bcp "SELT  * FROM PRODUCT" queryout ing_product.txt -T -S99.999.999.9,99999 -t"\t" -c -q
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BAT files are not PoSh code ... and they don't trigger a _stop_ error ... and the `try/catch` construct REQUIRES a _stop_ error. ///// why are you using BAT files? the `bcp.exe`  util should run properly when called from in a ps1 file. ///// also, the `bcp.exe` util seems to be doing SQL queries ... and powershell has cmdlets for that ... so, why use that util instead of the PoSh cmdlets?

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are only thrown/caught when [terminating errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58828208/584676) are thrown, which are only thrown by cmdlets, .NET libraries, or native code when `P/Invoke` is in play. In order to handle failures with external commands, such as checking whether a `bat` or `exe` succeeded, you will need to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` yourself. `$LASTEXITCODE` is the PowerShell equivalent of `%ERRORLEVEL%` in `cmd.exe`. Here is an example of some basic boilerplate code to check this for the ping command:

```
&ping nonexistant.domain.tld
if( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ){
  # Handle the error here
  # This example writes to the error stream and throws a terminating error
  Write-Error "Unable to ping server, ping returned $LASTEXITCODE" -EA Stop
}
```

---

> Note that the `-ErrorAction` argument has a shorthand of `-EA`, so either the long or short form will work.